# Sort a list depends on another sorted list which has one attribute in common for sorting

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, collections

Sorry for long description but I tried to explain the content precisely,

I have two lists of different objects like,

```
class Company {
     int id;
     String name;
     /* getters and setters */
}

class CompanyBySupplier {
     String nameId;
     Long stakeValue;
     Long incomeValue;
     /* getters and setters */
}
```

Common attribute in these list is, `id` of Company and `nameId` of `CompanyBySupplier`

`listToSort` is list of objects of `CompanyBySupplier` and `sortedList` is list of objects of `Company`,

```
List<CompanyBySupplier> listToSort = {["ID3,546456,56464"],["ID4",4565,456456],["ID1,1234,2345"],["ID2",4335,34535],["ID5,345,546"]}

List<Company> sortedList = {["ID1","A"],["ID2","B"],["ID3","C"],["ID4","D"],["ID5","E"]}
```

If you observe `sortedList` is already sorted depending on name attribute which I want to do for `lisToSort` indirectly.

that means, I need `listToSort` in the order of `sortedList` with comparison of `id` of `Company` and `nameId` of `CompanyBySupplier`

So the expected output should be,

```
list listToSort = {["ID1,1234,2345"],["ID2",4335,34535],["ID3,546456,56464"],["ID4",4565,456456],["ID5,345,546"]}
```

Because ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4,ID5 is the order in sortedList of Company.

What I can think of is creating a new list by comparing id and nameid of two lists which will contains new type of object like,

```
class CompanyData {
     String actualCompanyName;
     Long stakeValue;
     Long incomeValue;
}
```

and use Comparator on actualCompanyName which will solve my problem.
But I'm interested in knowing is there any other better way of doing this

Comment: Is this java? Object Company {...} - what is it?

Comment: And List<Company> sortedList = {["ID1","A"]... , but Company class(if it's java) has int and String fields, there are 2 String fields

Comment: @Alexei Stepanov yes it is java object but just for sake of visual understanding I mentioned it like this

Comment: You can create a hashmap for sortedList with nameId as key and index as value. Now for every object in listToSort, search for the id and put the object at respective index.

Comment: @Sandy thanks I did the same it saved my extra  iteration for for loop

Answer (score 1):

Your sorted list is already sorted on the base of Id. You can sort you second list on the base of same id.

```
List<CompanyBySupplier> listToSort = new List<CompanyBySupplier> { new CompanyBySupplier() { nameId = "ID3", stakeValue = "546456", incomeValue = "56464" }, new CompanyBySupplier() { nameId = "ID4", stakeValue = "546456", incomeValue = "56464" }, new CompanyBySupplier() { nameId = "ID2", stakeValue = "546456", incomeValue = "56464" }, new CompanyBySupplier() { nameId = "ID1", stakeValue = "2345", incomeValue = "2346" } };
                List<Company> sortedList = new List<Company>() { new Company(){ id = "ID1", name = "A" }, new Company() { id = "ID2", name = "B" }, new Company() { id = "ID3", name = "C" } };


                listToSort.Sort(delegate(CompanyBySupplier x, CompanyBySupplier y) 
                {
                    return x.nameId.CompareTo(y.nameId);
                });

                foreach (var item in listToSort)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(item.nameId);
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        public class Company
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
        }

        public class CompanyBySupplier
        {
            public String nameId;
            public string stakeValue;
            public string incomeValue;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you raza.hasnain for your help but I;m looking for java collection solution